# Работа в StackOverflow?

Tags: обсуждение

Каким образом можно попасть на работу разрабом в SO?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Список вакансий есть на специальной странице: https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here

Comment: Что насчёт русского SO?

Comment: @hedgehogues вроде когда-то говорилось, что русский SO владельцам не особо интересен

Comment: @andreymal почему? Как он тогда вообще существует?

Comment: @hedgehogues, в компании, как я понял, нет разделения на сайты.

Comment: @Grundy Т.е. единая система и там всё лежит? Так что ли? Ну, есть же ответственные за русский SO?

Comment: @hedgehogues, community manager? :) Или с точки зрения разработки?

Comment: @Grundy С точки зрения разработки я понял. Там всё одно. Ну, да, вероятно. я не заню, как административная часть устроена. Есть некий парень (не помню, как зовут), который здесь часто на баннерах мелькает

Comment: @hedgehogues вероятно, вы имеете ввиду [Николая Чабановского](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky), он community manager.

Comment: А, Да. Это добровольная история? Или работа?

Comment: @hedgehogues, он сотрудник https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/282647

Comment: @hedgehogues раньше был владельцем хешкода. Потом SE купили хешкод, и тот стал ruSO. Теперь Николай работает менеджером в компании с расширенными полномочиями на ruSO.